# Access Violation while trying to get an element from SDL_Surface

Tags: visual-c++, sdl

Visual Studio Express 2012's debugger says:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00B8147F in PFPJ.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation 
reading location 0x00000008.
```

Here is the part of the code that the debugger says is the problem:

(Just so you know, `width` and `height` are declared globally in `main.cpp`. All of the functions utilizing these variables are within `main.cpp`.

```
SDL_Surface* bmmap = NULL;
bmmap = SDL_LoadBMP( file );
width = bmmap -> w;
height = bmmap -> h;
```

Specifically the `width = bmmap -> w` returns the error.

```
Problem signature:
 Problem Event Name:        APPCRASH
 Application Name:          PFPJ.exe
 Application Version:       0.0.0.0
 Application Timestamp:     51a57a2e
 Fault Module Name:         PFPJ.exe
 Fault Module Version:      0.0.0.0
 Fault Module Timestamp:    51a57a2e
 Exception Code:            c0000005
 Exception Offset:          00001838
 OS Version:                6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
 Locale ID:                 1033
 Additional Information 1:  0a9e
 Additional Information 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
 Additional Information 3:  0a9e
 Additional Information 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Every other example I've found for getting width or height out of an `SDL_Surface*` uses this notation. I don't fully understand what is going on.

What I am certain of is that my own in-built file stream has an output file that shows me where it failed. It fails in a different function when it references width/height in a double for loop. SDL_Surface structs are defined as:

```
typedef struct SDL_Surface {
 Uint32 flags;                           /* Read-only */
 SDL_PixelFormat *format;                /* Read-only */
 int w, h;                               /* Read-only */
 Uint16 pitch;                           /* Read-only */
 void *pixels;                           /* Read-write */
 SDL_Rect clip_rect;                     /* Read-only */
 int refcount;                           /* Read-mostly */
 } SDL_Surface;
```

This blows me away. I don't understand where this error comes from, and why this is a problem. It works within the context of the function where I used the `->` notation. I've found a number of programs that use `surface -> w` to get the width, so what's the problem?

(I'm relatively new to C/C++, so any insight is helpful)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this line is failing

```
bmmap = SDL_LoadBMP( file );
```

When it fails, it returns `NULL` (i.e. zero). Then when you dereference this zero address to get the width (at some offset in the struct - I'm guessing it's 8 bytes), you get an access violation at memory address 0x00000008.

Add a check to make sure that the `SDL_LoadBMP` has succeeded.

Comment: Oh, interesting. How should I check that it works? I thought it only returned the pointer to the SDL_Surface struct. Also, it does work as far as I am aware. I have a function that turns the surface into a two dimensional array, and I printed the array to be sure... [I think] it works as it should.

Comment: Well, just add a test `if (bmmap == NULL) printf("Error")` or similar and see what you get. Then find out why `SDL_LoadBMP` is failing ...

Comment: Yeah, the BMP is definitely loading properly. No error. Any idea why it is singling out those two lines as the culprit? Because within the function, width and height are fine and produce the image as expected.

Comment: Well, dereferencing a null pointer to the width in that struct will give exactly that error, so it's a sign that somewhere you have a null pointer that you've not trapped. If it's not in the line of code you indicated, then perhaps you need to post the code that actually causes the error so we can see what might be happening.

Comment: I think I may post a link to the full code. Seems you might be right about the pointer. I started printing values for x and y in the iteration where it is being used... it is giving me random numbers in the 1,000,000 to 5,000,000 range. In this case, the iteration relies on width and height to determine the range it has to stop in.

I think the debugger is right, it must be related to that pointer. What is peculiar to me is why it could go from right to wrong like that. It worked in the function where the value is given, I figured since it was globally defined, that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The width and height being returned is correct. The for loops utilize these numbers. Now I am definitely confused.